# iOS Viewport issues in cordova (viewport overlaps device)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, cordova, meteor

I am facing a very weird issue on my latest cordova app and can not find any explanation. Maybe someone has encountered a similar issue and knows what causes it... And maybe even knows how to work around it.

After a iOS user uses an upload form to upload images and then closes the modal of the uploading screen, the viewport seems to be too big for the screen.

Normall the app looks like this: 
[This is how it should look...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5HfQ.jpg)

But when I uploaded an image (it goes to Imagelibrary selection, and then back to the app), the following issues appear:
 1. Viewport seems too big (specially visible on the fixed footer). 
 2. The statusbar is suddenly transparent (this is not very important, but still weird)...

The App looks as follows after the error:
[How it looks like with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQjV4.jpg)

Also I noticed, that this happens on another app as well, after the user comes back from a native component (the other app uses a QR-Code scanner and when the scanner closes the same thing happens). Seems familiar, as in this case the picture selection is also a native component...

**What I tried so far:**

1. I tried looking at viewport meta tags and change them to the correct scale, but the value never changes...
2. I tried to force a hard refresh (`location.reload()`), but it reloads with the same error...
3. I also tried `navigator.app.loadUrl()` and `window.location` both do not change anything

   Also, the problem only shows on iPhones. I tested on an old iPad mini, no issues there and Android works like a champ as well...

The viewport is set as follows: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />`

And the upload is a simple file-upload input :)

** Edit **
Found, that document.documentElement.clientHeight changes after the upload, it changes from 647 to 687... Why though? And how could I reset it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!